# Using OpenCV rotation and translation in iOS Metal to draw AR cube

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality, metal

I am new to playing the AR, computer vision and graphics. I am trying to use make a AR experience using OpenCV and Metal in iOS. Rotation and Translation was retrieved by SolvePnP and passed to Metal to draw the cube pose.

However, there are a few problems:

1. The cube jump out of the view as soon as the R and T are passed.
2. Even can see the cube sometimes, the rotation seems not match with phone movement.
3. Translation values seems not doing to move the cube with respect to phone movement. Therefore, failed to anchor to any surface or a point at space.

I can provide more information to analysis my problem if needed. Thank you.